# filling factor, landau fan, and landau index

Tags: quantum-hall-effect

In the [paper here](https://www.nature.com/articles/nature26160#supplementary-information), there is a plot of $R_{xx}$ as a function of magnetic field $B_{⊥}$  and carrier density, $n$.

The filling factor jumps by 4 between adjacent lines.

The set of lines where $R_{xx}= 0$ seems to be defined as 'Landau fan.'

$R_{xx}=0$ when the fermi energy is between bands, as shown in this image below (from wikipedia).  [image: From wikipedia]

I was also able to find in the paper [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/16712020) that for graphene with 4 fold degeneracy, $\nu = \pm 4(|n|+1/2)$.

I would like to know the general relation between the filling factor and the landau level (I wasn't able to find a clear equation showing the relation between the two. For instance, the equation I found for four fold degenerate graphene, on top of the factor of 4, it has an offset of $1/2$.

Comment: The Landau level _is_ the filling factor, both terms are employed to say the same thing. Now, for the factor 4 : in graphene, there are two types of degeneracy : there is the two equivalent sub-lattices degeneracy (usually referred to as __K__ and __K'__ valleys) from which comes a factor of 2. There is also an electron-hole degeneracy from which comes another factor of 2. Now you have the factor 4. For the 1/2 offset, as I am not so familiar with graphene, I forgot where it comes from. Hope it helps.